# Twilio: Queue and Member

Tags: twilio

How to create queue member with incoming phone number in twilio. I want to list all the phone number which are in queued with grouping. Let's say there are three group call Collection tree , Sales tree and insidesales tree. I want to list all queued number grouping with those group.
For example,
Collection Tree:

1. +158099898877  queued
2. +989888888887 queued

Sales Tree
1. +17873737373 queued
2. +17666363636 queued

It is possible to create queue member like above example.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can get a list of all of the members of a specific queue by using the Members resource:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#list

Hope that helps.

Comment: I went through that link you mentioned above.I think that was for listing all the historical queued information saved by twilio in their database.I am talking about the more than one phone number which are currently located in queue(waiting for answering).Let say  some already call to my twilio number and some one talking with client . Another client (say client2) dial  to same twilio number and my number is busy and  then client2 number waiting for answer(client2 phone number is still in queued).

Comment: Similarly there are more than one client dail at same twilio number then twilio put those all phone number in queue list right?.I want to list those queued phone number (that are currently waiting for answering) with some group. This is my scenario.How could i separate waiting list of queued in different groupwise?.

Comment: The Members resource represents a list of Calls currently sitting in a specific queue (based on the Queue SID you specify in the request URL).  Its not historical data.  If you want to get a list of calls actually currently sitting in one of your queues this is the resource you need to request.  Maybe I'm not understanding exactly what you are trying to do.